# Cannot load in .csv using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

This is my code for loading in the CSV I want:

```
const fs = require('fs')
var parse = require('csv-parse')
var data;
fs.readFile('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/blahblah/data.csv', function(err, fileData) {
  parse(fileData, {
    columns: false,
    trim: true
  }, function(err, rows) {
    console.log(rows);
    data = rows;
  })
})
```

The problem is that `rows` shows up to be `undefined`. I'm completely new to Node.js so this might be a silly question, but how do I get it to be stored into that variable?

I want to then use d3.js to make some pretty graphs from the data. I know I already installed csv-parse and fs because they show up in my node-modules folder.

Comment: What value should `rows` have when you pass it into the `parse` function?

Comment: It should be an array of arrays containing the data from the csv file

Comment: IIRC `fs` cannot handle urls - with exception to the `file:` protocol. You might want to try [`http.get()`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback), or maybe the [Request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) package to load in your data from external urls.

Comment: Ah, okay awesome. I think that was the fix! One more thing; is it possible to read in multiple files in a row, or do I have to request all of them separately?